# Json array don't show me 5 or more Rows on PHP Script to a SQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, json

When I'm trying to perform basic CRUD operation on my database, but here when I tried to get a single row from my database whit a php script, I see the correct data from my database, but when I'm put more rows on de data base, and I tried to get the data, it never appears.

I'm using this PHP Script

```
<?php 
//Importing Database Script 
require_once('Connectdb.php');

//Creating sql query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ensaladas ";

//getting result 
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//creating a blank array 
$result = array();

//looping through all the records fetched
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
    //Pushing name and id in the blank array created 
    array_push($result,array(
        "ensid"=>$row['ensid'],
        "nombre"=>$row['nombre'],
        "precio"=>$row['precio'],
    ));
}

//Displaying the array in json format 
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And gives me the next result:

[image]

I use this when the table has 2 rows, and when I put another rows, the code stop Working. The table of the database has 3 fields: ensid,nombre,precio. As you can see here:

[image]

PD: I'm using this script to get the data on an Android APP

Comment: Did the provided answer helped you or you still have same problem after changing those issues? Because I can not reproduce your error on my machine. Also from what I can see, you result is not **Empty**, you are getting an **Unexpected error**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Error checking

Do some [error checking](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) on your part. You can also try to run the query at the back-end of your system (PhpMyAdmin).

### Fetching data

Since you are using `mysqli_*` API already, try using [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT ensid, nombre, precio FROM ensaladas");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($ensid, $nombre, $precio);
while($stmt->fetch()){

    array_push($result, array(
        "ensid"=>$ensid,
        "nombre"=>$nombre,
        "precio"=>$precio,
    ));

}
$stmt->close();
```

### Displaying the data

You can then now display all the data using:

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

Or if you want a specific row from the result, you can use an index:

```
echo json_encode($result[$x]); /* $x REPRESENTS THE INDEX; INTEGER VALUE */
```

Or get a specific data from a specific row:

```
echo json_encode($result[$x]['ensid']); /* EITHER ensid, nombre, or precio */
```

Answer (score 0):

When I took a look into your database selection example(screen), the table name that you are querying is 'bebidas', while in the screenshot of the database you have used 'ensaladad'.

Try to use:

```
// Creating SQL query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ensaladas ";
```

or use:

```
 // looping through all the records fetched
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){

     // Pushing name and id in the blank array created 
     array_push($result,$row));
 }
```

Comment: that's true, uploaded the wrong script, but i tried to use mysqli_fetch_assoc, instead of mysqli_fetch_array, and the result is the same: empty. Tanks for the answer i already edited the Script.